# Manipulating images. Nhibernate + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, database, image, nhibernate

I have an entity like

```
[Serializable]
public class Person : AbstractEntity<Person>
{
    public virtual Byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using NHibernate 3.x. Howcome do I avoid saving the blob `Image` to a database (`SQL Server Express 2010`)? Any better alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: is it web application?if so, you might wanna store the path of the image, makes more sense to me..

Comment: Mark the property virtual and don't map it in the .hbm file?

Comment: I've got two applications intranet and internet. Should I store paths to an image on a server? What about image uploading then?

Comment: well that is is what I do normally..

Comment: @AnarchistGeek add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you save the image, save it to a non-obvious folder, and change the name of the image file to a unique filename(I assume you have a ID field which you can use), save the filename to database. 
lets say you want to bind a view with person model, you could do something like

```
<img src='imagepath/model.imagepath'/>
```

this is I used to use for my site, and I have a home project which I follow same method. it is just an alternative to store pics as blob.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Make your property readonly

```
<property name="..." column="..." insert="false" update="false" />
```

or if you are using mapping by code then

```
Property(p => p.Image, m =>
{
    m.Column("...");
    m.Insert(false);
    m.Update(false);
});
```